# How to make keyboard inputs into a function to reduce clutter

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, keyboard

this is a question that is solely for organizational purposes, but in pygame, is it possible to put keyboard inputs into a function. I am using pycharm, and from pycharm I am using pygame. The code

```
 if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print("Press")
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            HomuraX_change = -0.5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            HomuraX_change = 0.5
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            HomuraX_change = 0
```

I tried using this in a function before putting it in a while loop. but this didn't work for some reason.

I put it in a function, such as

```
def movement():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       print("Press")
       if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
           HomuraX_change = -0.5
       if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
           HomuraX_change = 0.5
   if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
           if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
           HomuraX_change = 0
```

and I put it in a while loop for my character movement. In the terminal for pygame, the "Print" from the second line was running, which showed that it worked in pycharm, however the charachter did not move. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the event as an argument to the function. The variable `HomuraX_change` needs to be declared [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt)

```py
def movement(event):
    global HomuraX_change 
    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        print("Press")
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            HomuraX_change = -0.5
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            HomuraX_change = 0.5
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            HomuraX_change = 0
```

```py
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        movement(event)

    # [...]
```